# How to redefine the = in python?

Tags: python, methods, operators, operator-overloading, redefine

I would to know what Python call when I use the `=`:

```
a = b
```

Where do I look for this information?

I would have the "assignment to variables" with my =

a would have a similar behaviour

```
l=list()  
l.append(1)  
l.append(2)  
l.append(3)  
l1=l  
l1[2] = ’B’  
print(l1)  
[1, 2, ’B’]  
print(l)  
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Why do you want to redefine the assignment operation? That's just asking for trouble.

Comment: Is this one of those times when you can obnoxiously yell **"THAT'S NOT *PYTHONIC!!!*"** without a care what "pythonic" means?

Comment: Serious question: What would you use it for?

Comment: @BoltClock - maybe you don't know what "pythonic" means yet, but you at least are recognizing practices that are *not* pythonic.

Comment: I would have the "assignment to variables" with my =

Comment: "I would have the "assignment to variables" with my ="?  What does this mean?  Python already assigns variables with `=`.  Since Python already does this, what are you talking about?  Are you confused about the semantics of assignment?

Comment: la=['a','b','c'] la1=la la1[1]='h' i want have two lists one             la->['a','b','c'] and la1->['a','h','c']

Comment: @fege: Simply copy the list: `la1 = la[:]`.  Also look at the `copy` module if you want to copy almost arbitrary objects.

Comment: i know that but i want redefine = for make automatic this, if it is possible

Comment: "i want redefine = for make automatic this"?  You want `=` to magically do list copy?  Do you realize how many things will break and be unusable because of this?  You would probably break **most** of the built-in library.  Parts of Python require sharing list objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or maybe you can do in this way:

```
def funct(obj):  
        import copy  
        print('entro')  
        return str(copy.deepcopy(obj))   
class metacl(type):  
        def __new__(meta,classname,supers,classdict):  
                classdict['__xxx__'] = funct  
                return type.__new__(meta,classname,supers,classdict)  
class list(list,metaclass=metacl): pass
```

I do not know which built-in function you must ovverride (**xxx**).
It is the unique way to use a metaclass, i think.

Answer (score 13):

You can't redefine `=` in Python.  It will always bind the object on the right-hand side to the name on the left-hand side.

Note that this is quite different from e.g. C++, where the `=` operator typically involves copying data to the target variable.  Python does not have variables in the sense C++ has.  Python has names that can be bound to objects.

Comment: i would change the behavior of =. i want try to emulate what do c++

Comment: If you want to use C++, then use C++.

Comment: @fege: Please tell us what you are trying to achieve.  Certainly there is a nice way to do it.

Comment: i would have the "assignment to variables" and not the "binding to values" with my =

Comment: It's better to use alternative syntax to make it explicit that data is copied. Redefining `=` would just be confusing for someone reading your code.

Answer (score 9):

You can't redefine `=`, but you *can* redefine:

```
a[c] = b
   or
a.c  = b
```

Do this by implementing [`__setitem__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__setitem__) or [`__setattr__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__setattr__), respectively. For attributes, it's often more appropriate to use [`property`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#property), but `__setattr__` has its uses.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot override `=` in Python. You can see the list of [special methods](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names) that you can override in the documentation and there's nothing to match `=` on that list.

Python always binds a name in your namespace to a value. This means that Python does't have "assignment to variables", it only has "binding to values": there's no data being copies, instead another reference is being added to the same value.

Answer (score 0):

You can override it, if you are inside a class.

For example:

```
class A(object):
    def __setattr__(self,name,value):
        print 'setting', name, 'to', value
```

Then:

```
A().foo = 'bar'
```

Would output:

```
setting foo to bar
```

Keep in mind, this would only modify that one class, not your entire program.

Comment: if this object is on the **LHS** of the assignment operation, yes. But not on the **RHS**